# D3 Map - JSON data exported from ESRI

Tags: javascript, d3.js, esri, topojson

I have a custom JSON file that a client has exported from ESRI. I'm still relatively novice working with D3's mapping features and am having some issues figuring out how to get this map aligned with my base map. For the base, I am using the US.json file in the following format:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
    {"type":"Feature",
     "id":"09",
     "properties": {
         "name":"Connecticut"
      },
     "geometry":{
         "type":"Polygon",
         "coordinates": [[[-73.053528,42.039048],[-71.799309,42.022617]...
```

The custom data I have been given is formatted differently and I'm not quite sure how to handle it. This is how it looks:

```
{"displayFieldName":"","fieldAliases":{"FID":"FID","WSA9":"WSA9","WSA9_NAME":"WSA9_NAME"},"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon","spatialReference":{"wkt":"PROJCS[\"Albers\"GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Albers\"],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-96.0],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",29.5],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",45.5],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",23.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]"},"fields":[{"name":"FID","type":"esriFieldTypeOID","alias":"FID"},{"name":"WSA9","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"WSA9","length":80},{"name":"WSA9_NAME","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"WSA9_NAME","length":80}],"features":[{"attributes":{"FID":0,"WSA9":"NAP","WSA9_NAME":"Northern Appalachians"},"geometry":{"rings":[[[1664894.6557,2097277.5137],[1665737.7609000001,2097197.3818000001]...
```

I see there are features and geometry properties in the file, so it made me think I should be able to work with the data, however, I noticed the D3 wiki does not include the geometry type "rings" in the list of geometry objects. Can I use this data? If so, how would I go about doing so? I have tried reformatting the data to the same structure as the above us.json data, using the follow block to try to get it to display, but no luck:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator(),
    path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

d3.json("data/NAP_Ecoregion_Merc.json")
    .then(function (data) {
      var region = map.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
    }
```

Thoughts? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ESRI json really has no relationship to geojson other than that they both hold geographic information. There are methods for converting ESRI json to geojson but you'll probably find it easier to convert a shapefile to geojson with something like mapshaper.org or command line tools.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll check and see if we can get a shapefile created.